# Distributed Cache/Session Solution for ASP.NET Web App

Tags: asp.net, session, caching, distributed, solution

I am looking for a distributed Cache/Session solution, below is what I found. I hope anyone could share information regarding pros and cons of using it:

1. [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)
2. [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849)
3. [MemCached](http://memcached.org/) as recommended by @TFD

I am using ASP.NET 4 and SQL Server 2008.

Any idea would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please share which one dis you use and what is your evaluation for it?

Answer (score 4):

You can also look at Redis (http://redis.io/), which is rumored to play very nicely with .NET applications thanks to an open source client for it written in C#: http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/ServiceStackRedis.

Answer (score 3):

Give Dache a go - an open source .NET distributed caching solution that is highly performant. http://www.getdache.net

Answer (score 2):

Use [memcached](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/), it's free, works well, runs on cheap *nix boxes, well proven

Memcached can be run on Windows for testing etc.

Various client libraries for .Net on [memcached/wiki/Clients](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/Clients)

And a pre-rolled [session and cache provider](http://memcachedproviders.codeplex.com/) if you don't feel like doing it yourself

---

If you are not familiar with *nix style OS's, [download Ubuntu server image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server/download) and burn to disc. Pop the disk into a empty machine with plenty of RAM and follow default prompts until finished (~30 minutes)

Then on the command line enter "apt-get install memcached"

Reboot to check it starts and all is OK and you are done

Comment: Thank you for your advice. You said: "Memcached can be run on Windows for testing etc." Is it no good for production using Windows? Can it be installed on the same machine as developement machine for developement purpose?

Comment: @Pingpong You can run multiple instances on same machine as a service for dev and test, or you can run in a VM too. It runs fine on Windows. For production you will have two or more separate (mostly, maybe also squid or varnish) dedicated machines (otherwise why are you bothering with it?), so you might as well use *nix and save resources

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will consider your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Try using NCache as it is one of the pioneer in the field of distributed caching. The wide range of caching topologies which NCache offered along with it's other features makes it probably the best cache provider in the  market. NCache is an enterprise level distributed cache for .NET and Java and also provides a fast and reliable storage for ASP.NET and JSP Sessions. As far as comparison of NCache with it's competitors are concerned, please watch this video,

[Feature comparison of NCache Vs AppFabric](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/demos/ncache-vs-appfabric.html)